# ActionMailer delivering email even if checkbox is not checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a checkbox (:notify) for Post, and I want to send emails when I create a new post, only if it is checked. However, ActionMailer is delivering the emails even if it is not checked. Here is the code snippet:

```
if @post.save
  unless params[:post][:notify].nil?
    PostMailer.notify_new(@post).deliver
  end
  .........
  ..............
```

Form:

```
= bootstrap_form_for @post, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_area :body
  = f.check_box :notify, label: ""
  = f.submit "Send", class: "button"
```

How do I fix it such that emails are delivered only when the notify checkbox is checked?
Thanks!

Comment: this has nothing to do with your action mailer. Your checkbox logic is in the view. And sending mail logic is (and should be) in controller. So apply filter in view to post only those requests to controller that are checked.

Comment: params could return `""` value, which is not nil. try `.present?` instead of `.nil?`

Comment: @shivam I'm sorry? This IS in the controller, in the create method.

Comment: @itsnikolay I've tried .present? as well, and it did not work.

Comment: @user3477051 do you want to show us your form? It's more likely that's where the issue is.

Comment: @moultonjr Sure, just edited.

Comment: @user3477051 which rails version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should move all this into the `Post` model...

```
class Post
  attr_accessor_with_default :notify, false
  after_create :deliver, :if => Proc.new {|p| p.notify}

  def deliver
    PostMailer.notify_new(self).deliver
  end
end
```

Then, notify will be treated as a boolean. Don't forget to permit `:notify` attribute in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check that `params[:post][:notify]` is the correct parameter to be looking for. If those parameters are always showing up, I'd look at your view logic. Also, if you're going to use this method of checking, change you condition to an if. For example:

```
if params[:post][:notify].present?
    PostMailer.notify_new(@post).deliver
end
```